# Env vars lost when building docker image from Gitlab CI

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, dockerfile, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to build my React / NodeJS project using Docker and Gitlab CI.

When I build manually my images, I use .env file containing env vars, and everything is fine.

```
docker build --no-cache -f client/docker/local/Dockerfile . -t espace_client_client:local
docker build --no-cache -f server/docker/local/Dockerfile . -t espace_client_api:local
```

But when deploying with Gitlab, I can build successfully the image, but when I run it, env vars are empty in the client.

Here is my gitlab CI:

```
image: node:10.15
variables:
  REGISTRY_PACKAGE_CLIENT_NAME: registry.gitlab.com/company/espace_client/client
  REGISTRY_PACKAGE_API_NAME: registry.gitlab.com/company/espace_client/api
  REGISTRY_URL: https://registry.gitlab.com
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
  # Client Side
  REACT_APP_API_URL: https://api.espace-client.company.fr
  REACT_APP_DB_NAME: company
  REACT_APP_INFLUX: https://influx-prod.company.fr
  REACT_APP_INFLUX_LOGIN: admin
  REACT_APP_HOUR_GMT: 2


stages:
  - publish

docker-push-client:
  stage: publish
  before_script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $REGISTRY_URL
  image: docker:stable
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker build --no-cache -f client/docker/prod/Dockerfile . -t $REGISTRY_PACKAGE_CLIENT_NAME:latest
    - docker push $REGISTRY_PACKAGE_CLIENT_NAME:latest
```

Here is the Dockerfile for the client

```
FROM node:10.15-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN npm -g install serve && npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "serve", "build", "-l", "3000" ]
```

Why is there such a difference between the 2 process ?

Comment: Hi. You've said *When I build manually my images, I use .env file containing env vars, and everything is fine.* and then *but when I run it, env vars are empty in the client.* Do you mean that building and deploying correct in both cases. And you have issues only with running, correct?

Comment: Yep, build and deploy are OK. But When I access the first page, I the login url is based on a env var, so no action on the first page is working, but it is rendered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your answer in comments, [GitLab CI/CD environment variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/) doesn't solve your issue. Gitlab CI environment is actual only in context of [GitLab Runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/) that builds and|or deploys your app.

So, if you are going to propagate Env vars to the app, there are several ways to deliver variables from `.gitlab-cy.yml`to your app:

## [`ENV`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) instruction Dockerfile

E.g.

```yaml
FROM node:10.15-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
ENV   NODE_ENV production
ENV   REACT_APP_API_URL: https://api.espace-client.company.fr
ENV   REACT_APP_DB_NAME: company
ENV   REACT_APP_INFLUX: https://influx-prod.company.fr
ENV   REACT_APP_INFLUX_LOGIN: admin
ENV   REACT_APP_HOUR_GMT: 2

RUN npm -g install serve && npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "serve", "build", "-l", "3000" ]
```

## docker-compose [`environment`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) directive

```yaml
web:
  environment:
    - NODE_ENV=production
    - REACT_APP_API_URL=https://api.espace-client.company.fr
    - REACT_APP_DB_NAME=company
    - REACT_APP_INFLUX=https://influx-prod.company.fr
    - REACT_APP_INFLUX_LOGIN=admin
    - REACT_APP_HOUR_GMT=2
```

## Docker [`run -e`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables)

> (Not your case, just for information)

`docker -e REACT_APP_DB_NAME="company"`

## P.S. Try Gitlab CI variables

There is convenient way to store variables outside of your code: [Custom environment variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#custom-environment-variables)

You can [set them up easily from the UI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#creating-a-custom-environment-variable). That can be very powerful as it can be used for scripting without the need to specify the value itself.

[image: creating-a-custom-environment-variable]
<sub>(source: [gitlab.com](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/img/new_custom_variables_example.png))</sub>

Comment: Putting env vars in client dockerfile worked ! Still don't know why it worked in local without that, but... it works !

Comment: BTW, I use Kubernetes, no Docker compose

Comment: HI @JuliatzindelToro, glad that tip helped. As for your concern *Still don't know why it worked in local*: possible cause hidden in `WORKDIR /app ... COPY . .`